# I want to record a liability when receiving inventory that isn't mine. What is the counterpart for this entry?

Tags: accounting, liability

When I receive inventory from a Vendor I would normally debit inventory for the value of the products and credit AP (sometimes moving the balance through an interim / clearing / unvouchered account if I record first the receipt and later the Bill).

In the case related to my question, I am receiving inventory from a Customer that I then process and sell a related product to them.

The Customer's inventory it isn't my asset and I don't want it reflected as an asset on the balance sheet, but I am responsible for the value of that inventory (if my facility burns down; if the inventory is stolen; or if someone at my facility damages it - my Customer will expect me to pay them for it).

So I would like to record the value of what I receive as a liability that can clear once I have used up that inventory in processing.

If I credit a liability account "value of inventory held" then what would the counterpart (debit) be?  I assume it has to be on my balance sheet to maintain "A + L + E".

Any ideas?  All comments welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your accountant , but...

...if it is not yours, then it is not yours. This is called segregation and is totally normal in the financial industry (brokers i.e. are no allowed to use customer funds for operations). This is NOT PART OF YOUR BALANCE - use a second balance sheet for this.

Comment: Thanks - I think "off-balance sheet" might be the way to go if I don't hear a more appealing option.

Comment: It is not so much off it as it is in a SEPARATE balance sheet.